# How do I use Capybara/Firefox with proxy on Heroku? I get "The proxy server is refusing connections"

Tags: selenium, heroku, capybara, http-proxy, geckodriver

I have the following code:

```
Capybara.register_driver :selenium_headless do |app|

  ...

  proxy = Selenium::WebDriver::Proxy.new(
    http: proxy_address,
    ssl: proxy_address
  )
  desired_caps = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities.firefox(
    proxy: proxy
  )

  Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, {
    browser: :firefox,
    desired_capabilities: desired_caps,
    ...
  })
end

driver = Capybara::Session.new(:selenium_headless)
driver.visit('https://api.ipify.org')
```

The code works without errors locally, as well as on Heroku if you remove all the proxy business (and forgo `browser_options`).

This code errors on Heroku with:

```
Selenium::WebDriver::Error::UnknownError (Reached error page: about:neterror?e=proxyConnectFailure&u=https%3A//api.ipify.org/&c=UTF-8&f=regular&d=Firefox%20is%20configured%20to%20use%20a%20proxy%20server%20that%20is%20refusing%20connections.)
```

That URL locally looks like this:

[image: proxy server is refusing connections]

When I turn on Selenium debug logs `Selenium::WebDriver.logger.level = :debug`, I get:

```
>>> http://127.0.0.1:4444/session/84439a4e-a26d-41f3-ae30-f61f508ca569/url | {"url":"https://api.ipify.org"}

{"value":{"error":"unknown error","message":"Reached error page: about:neterror?e=proxyConnectFailure&u=https%3A//api.ipify.org/&c=UTF-8&f=regular&d=Firefox%20is%20configured%20to%20use%20a%20proxy%20server%20that%20is%20refusing%20connections.","stacktrace":"WebDriverError@chrome://marionette/content/error.js:179:5\nUnknownError@chrome://marionette/content/error.js:484:5\nhandleReadyState@chrome://marionette/content/listener.js:273:21\nhandleEvent@chrome://marionette/content/listener.js:242:14\n"}
```

My proxy options are logged roughly like `"proxy":{"httpProxy":"207.000.00.00:0000","proxyType":"manual","sslProxy":"207.000.00.00:0000"}`

Thanks in advance for the help!

Update: The proxy service I'm using works outside with Capybara. I test with `OpenURI`.

Comment: It sounds like the proxy provider is blocking connections from Heroku - you can’t workaround that (other than running your code from a non-blocked location)

Comment: @ThomasWalpole that's what I guessed, but here's what confused me:

I can connect to the proxy provider through OpenURI, fetch a webpage (https://api.ipify.org/), and determine the webpage-fetching IP was changed.

Let me try again to be sure...